# C# Modulus Counting

Tags: c#

Good Day,

I am writing an application where I'm downloading a file that is over 30MB.  I am keeping track of how many bytes that have been currently been downloaded.

My question is:

I want to determine when I go past 1M, 2M, 3M and so forth.

My logic is:

```
int totalFileSave = 0;
...
...
int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
totalFileSave += bytesRead;

while (bytesRead > 0) {
    // How do I test when I hit 1M, 2M, 3M and so forth...
    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
    totalFileSave += bytesRead;
}
```

Comment: From your title it seems you have an idea how to solve this yourself.  What have you tried which hasn't worked?

Comment: @Russell, when I initially tried:

if totalFileSave = 1049201 then
    totalFileSave % 1000000 = 49201, which isn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
private const int megaByte = 1024 * 1024;
private int current = 0;

while (bytesRead > 0) 
{
    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
    totalFileSave += bytesRead;

    int total = bytesRead / megaByte;

    if (total > current)
    {
        current = total;
        // you went up 1 M and are now at or greater than 'current'M
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private const int MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

if ((bytesRead % MEGABYTE) == 0)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: When will bytesRead ever exceed 4096?